# Failure while fetching StreamChunkId

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I have two data sets on S3. One is a about 200g and other is about 2tb. There is a relation between two and for one record in first one there can be multiple records in second. 
I am doing spark sql join on some common columns for these two data sets. I have run this job successfully on AWS EMR in one of our development environment where the data size is almost same.
When trying to run this on upper environment we are getting following error

```
 org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Too large frame: 5167960326
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 5167960326
```

Then i increased the number of partition and now i am seeing a different error which is here :

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failure while fetching StreamChunkId{streamId=762306475013, chunkIndex=0}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to open file: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512595465967_0004/blockmgr-2d23cec5-d6ea-40ea-a757-38043ca20cdc/28/shuffle_2_1009_0.index
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getSortBasedShuffleBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:249)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:174)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler$1.next(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:105)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler$1.next(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.OneForOneStreamManager.getChunk(OneForOneStreamManager.java:89)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processFetchRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512595465967_0004/blockmgr-2d23cec5-d6ea-40ea-a757-38043ca20cdc/28/shuffle_2_1009_0.index (No such file or directory)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2410)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2380)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getSortBasedShuffleBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:240)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512595465967_0004/blockmgr-2d23cec5-d6ea-40ea-a757-38043ca20cdc/28/shuffle_2_1009_0.index (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ShuffleIndexInformation.<init>(ShuffleIndexInformation.java:41)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver$1.load(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:111)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver$1.load(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:109)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    ... 40 more

    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at com.deere.isg.sparkdatautility.SparkWorker.writePartitionFiles(SparkWorker.scala:148)
    at com.deere.isg.sparkdatautility.implicits.package$DataFileWriter$$anonfun$writeDatumPartitions$2.apply(implicits.scala:246)
    at com.deere.isg.sparkdatautility.implicits.package$DataFileWriter$$anonfun$writeDatumPartitions$2.apply(implicits.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.network.client.ChunkFetchFailureException: Failure while fetching StreamChunkId{streamId=762306475013, chunkIndex=0}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to open file: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512595465967_0004/blockmgr-2d23cec5-d6ea-40ea-a757-38043ca20cdc/28/shuffle_2_1009_0.index
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getSortBasedShuffleBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:249)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:174)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler$1.next(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:105)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler$1.next(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.OneForOneStreamManager.getChunk(OneForOneStreamManager.java:89)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processFetchRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at org.spark_project.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512595465967_0004/blockmgr-2d23cec5-d6ea-40ea-a757-38043ca20cdc/28/shuffle_2_1009_0.index (No such file or directory)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2410)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2380)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getSortBasedShuffleBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:240)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1512595465967_0004/blockmgr-2d23cec5-d6ea-40ea-a757-38043ca20cdc/28/shuffle_2_1009_0.index (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ShuffleIndexInformation.<init>(ShuffleIndexInformation.java:41)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver$1.load(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:111)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver$1.load(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:109)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    ... 40 more

    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:120)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

The EMR cluster that i am using has 20 nodes r3.8xlarge with 244g of memory.
    Here is the EMR config that i am using to submit the job.

```
    --driver-memory 180g 
    --driver-cores 30 
    --num-executors 40 
    --executor-memory 80g
    --executor-cores 1
    --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=35g
    --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=50g
    --conf spark.network.timeout=1200s
```

Partitions -  1000000 (This is done at the code level, passed as argument)

I have tried increasing the network time out to spark.network.timeout=1200s but still seeing the same result.

Any help would be really appriciated`

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: @ImanAkbari Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46651540/2516356